# How can I find out a screen device's power failure : xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Is there an events or way to find out a screen device's power failure.
I need to flag on a remote device if all the parts are working.
I found ways for most off the elements but for the screen I could only find events that tells if screen is on sleep or active but nothings to detect if a screen is powerless or broken. Could not find any code sample to workaround. As a beginner I do not know how to resolve. Anny hints would be welcome.

I haven't started coding this up yet. This is more investigative than anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never tried to detect an error with the screen, it doesn't look like there is much on this. If the screen is broken, the low-level device driver plumbing may not even give you any information or incorrect information. You might check out 
[DisplayManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html) as it contains a `DisplayListener` which may notify you when a display such as the main device display is disconnected but it sounds like it is more for external displays you are connecting to the device. Closest I could find.

Comment: that is were i was looking and i was more or less thinking the same